# Unable to setup dap for go

Tags: golang

I am trying to setup the new dap plugin for Go in emacs, but I am unable to.
This is documentation that i am following:
https://emacs-lsp.github.io/dap-mode/page/configuration/#go

This is my configuration

```el
(require 'dap-dlv-go)
```

This is the error that i am getting

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (file-missing "Cannot open load file" "No such file or directory" "dap-dlv-go")
  require(dap-dlv-go)
  eval((require 'dap-dlv-go) nil)
  elisp--eval-last-sexp(nil)
  eval-last-sexp(nil)
  funcall-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil)
  call-interactively(eval-last-sexp nil nil)
  command-execute(eval-last-sexp)
```

When I try with use-package

```el
(use-package dap-dlv-go
  :ensure t)
```

I get this error:

```
File is missing: Cannot open load file, No such file or directory, dap-dlv-go
```

Please help, Am I missing something here

I have also tried to refresh package list, still it does not work.

Comment: How did you install dap-mode? I had the same issue when installing version 0.7 from melpa-stable, but it's working with the latest version from melpa.

Answer (score 0):

```el
(use-package dap-mode :ensure t) ;; package contains the sub mode
(require 'dap-dlv-go) 
;;; find other options to configure 
;;; https://emacs-lsp.github.io/dap-mode/page/configuration/#go
```